# grep regex to perl or awk

Tags: perl, awk, solaris, pcre, nawk

I have been using Linux env and recently migrated to solaris. Unfortunately one of my bash scripts requires the  use of `grep` with the `P` switch [ pcre support ] .As Solaris doesnt support the `pcre` option for grep , I am obliged to find another solution to the problem.And `pcregrep` seems to have an obvious  loop bug and  `sed` `-r` option is unsupported !
I hope that using `perl` or `nawk` will solve the problem on solaris.

I have not yet used `perl` in my script and am unware neither of its syntax nor the flags.

Since it is `pcre` , I beleive that a `perl` scripter can help me out in a matter of minutes. They should match over multiple lines .

Which one would be a better solution in terms of efficiency the `awk`  or the `perl` solution ?

Thanks for the replies .

Comment: Did you try to use the regex with perl? It is worth a try as the name `pcre` does indicate certain Perl compatibility.

Comment: Have you checked to see if your system has the GNU grep installed under an alternate path such as `/usr/gnu/bin`, `/usr/sfw/bin`, `/usr/local/bin`, `/opt/csw/bin`, or similar?  Then you'd just need to change the path to grep in your script, not rewrite it to a new command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are some `grep` to `perl` conversions you might need:

`grep -P PATTERN FILE(s)`   --->  `perl -nle 'print if m/PATTERN/' FILE(s)`

`grep -Po PATTERN FILE(s)`  --->  `perl -nle 'print "$1\n" while m/(PATTERN)/g' FILE(s)`

That's my guess as to what you're looking for, if `grep -P` is out of the question.

Comment: You mean `perl -nle 'print if /PATTERN/' FILES`.

Comment: Thanks, yeah just ran some tests and came to that conclusion! Next time, feel free to edit.

Comment: I believe that the second one should be more like: `perl -nle 'print $1 while /(PATTERN)/g'`

Comment: I would also prefer `perl -nlE 'say $1 if /(PATTERN)/' FILE` for the second for brevity.

Comment: Ok, it's all sorted out. Thanks for the additions.

Comment: @kevlar1818 Unfortunately it doesnt work for the same regex :( but I tried with another regex and it works great ! I have now added a sample i/p file .

Comment: Some versions of Perl don't have `say` or require that it be explicitly enabled. The `-l` option makes it unnecessary since it automatically sets `$\ = "\n"` so `print` will output newlines.

Comment: I cant seem to match the `perl` code for the pattern mentioned in the question , over multiple lines [single line matches are ok ] !  Am I missing something here ?

Comment: `perl -0777pe 'print $1 while /(pattern with\nnewlines)/g'`. See also the `/m` and `/s` options, although I imagine they should be familiar from PCRE land. The basic issue here is that Perl runs the script on one input line at a time by default.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a shorty:

```
 grep -P /regex/ ====> perl -ne 'print if /regex/;'
```

- The `-n` takes each line of the file as input. Each line is put into a special perl variable called `$_` as Perl loops through the whole file.
- The `-e` says the Perl program is on the command line instead of passing it a file.
- The Perl `print` command automatically prints out whatever is in `$_` if you don't specify for it to print out anything else.
- The `if /regex/` matches the regular expression against whatever line of your file is in the `$_` variable.